# Displaying Popup for Single Array Element from API Call ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

Sorry if I worded this poorly, it's my first question, and I'm also new to JS/React in general...

I have mapped through an array from an API call and displayed the information I need; how can I show a popup for a single element in the array returned rather than displaying the information for all elements?

```
        import React, {useState, useEffect, useCallback} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import Popup from 'reactjs-popup';
import 'reactjs-popup/dist/index.css';

function Agents() {

    let [responseData, setResponseData] = useState([]);
    let [doneLoading, setdoneLoading] = useState(false);
    let [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    let closePopup = () => setOpen(false);
  
    const fetchData = useCallback(() => {
        axios({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'https://valorant-api.com/v1/agents',
          params: {language: 'en-US', isPlayableCharacter: true}
        })
        .then((response) => {
          setResponseData(response.data.data.map(m => ({a: m.displayName, b: m.mapUrl, c: m.displayIcon})))
          console.log(responseData)
          setdoneLoading(true)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
        })
      }
    )
  
    useEffect(() => {
      fetchData()
    }, []) // pass an empty array as the dependencies
  
    return (
        <div>
            <h1 class="text-3xl text-white text-center p-4">Valorant Agents</h1>
            <h2 class="text-xl text-white text-center">Click on an agent to learn more</h2>
            <div class="bg-slate-500 grid grid-cols-5 gap-4 max-h-screen" key={responseData}>

                {doneLoading ? 
                Object(responseData).map((maps, index) => {
                console.log( JSON.stringify(maps) + "Hex?")
                return (
                    <div key={responseData.maps} class="">

                        <div class="flex-col justify-center items-center p-2 border bg-slate-500 rounded-xl hover:bg-slate-700 cursor-pointer" onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>
                          <p class="text-white text-center font-semibold">{`${index+1}. ${maps.a}`}</p>
                          <img src={maps.c} alt="#" width="75px" class="mx-auto"/> 
                          <div onClick={() => setOpen(true)} class="text-center text-white font-semibold pt-1">Learn more</div>
                        </div>
                        {open ? 
                        <>
                        <div class="text-center text-white">Returned API information would go here</div>
                        <button onClick={closePopup} class="text-white border p-1 flex justify-center mx-auto">Close</button>
                        </>
                        : null}
                                            
                    </div>  
                    )
                })
                : console.log("loading")
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Agents
```

So in the code above, I toggle a (not so styled yet) popup which should display information for the individual div clicked; however, it shows the information for all instead. I was hoping someone could educate me as I'm still learning; all I've gathered so far is that it displays all the information inside the map method. I'm just not sure how to approach it outside of that.

Edit - Here is a [CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-cloud-gx27du?file=/src/App.js); if you click to learn more, it displays on all the characters, but I only want it for the individual one clicked.

Comment: Where is your popup? Would you add it so that we can provide an example solution?

Comment: @jifakir sorry I should have clarified, I haven't styled a popup yet but you can assume I'd want the information in the div where it says "returned information would go here"

Comment: Hi @Adipep00 , You can provide code by codesandbox link, That will show the code more clearly.

Comment: Hi @MOLLY hopefully this link works as I haven't used that before, when I click learn more I only want it to display info for the character clicked but it instead does it for all https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-cloud-gx27du?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Adipep00 hi~ Try the link what i updated in answer. I think it can help you~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this~~~

Here is updated link: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/small-bird-67nms5?file=/src/App.js:1430-1446)

You can view code start with Line 36,
The component PopUp can change to want you want (I just write ii in most simple way)

The main knoweldge is you should pass the data to PopUp component.

```
...
  const [showData, setShowData] = useState();
  const PopUp = (props) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{props.data.a}</h1>
        <div class="text-center text-white">
          Returned API information would go here
        </div>
        <button
          onClick={closePopup}
          class="text-white border p-1 flex justify-center mx-auto"
        >
          Close
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  };
  const throwDataToPopUp = (data) => {
    setOpen(true);
    setShowData(data);
  };
...
```

Comment: @Adipep00 It's glad to help you :) !

Answer (score 0):

When we click on any item, we should catch that data in a state.
Then, we should show that state data in the popup.

```
const [modalData, setModalData] = React.useState(null); // this state is to store the item data
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

const handleModalOpen = (itemData) => {
  setModalData(itemData);   
  setOpen(true);
};

const closeModal = () => {
   setModalData(null);
   setOpen(false);
};
    
return (
      <div>
            <h1 class="text-3xl text-white text-center p-4">Valorant Agents</h1>
            <h2 class="text-xl text-white text-center">Click on an agent to learn more</h2>
            <div class="bg-slate-500 grid grid-cols-5 gap-4 max-h-screen" key={responseData}>

                {doneLoading ? 
                Object(responseData).map((maps, index) => {
                console.log( JSON.stringify(maps) + "Hex?")
                return (
                    <div key={responseData.maps} class="">

                        <div class="flex-col justify-center items-center p-2 border bg-slate-500 rounded-xl hover:bg-slate-700 cursor-pointer" onClick={() => handleModalOpen(maps)}>
                          <p class="text-white text-center font-semibold">{`${index+1}. ${maps.a}`}</p>
                          <img src={maps.c} alt="#" width="75px" class="mx-auto"/> 
                          <div onClick={() => handleModalOpen(maps)} class="text-center text-white font-semibold pt-1">Learn more</div> // When we click on there, it saves the item data we are getting as maps into state and opening the popup same time.
                        </div>
                        {open ? 
                        <>
                        <div class="text-center text-white">Returned info would go here</div>
                        <button onClick={closeModal} class="text-white border p-1 flex justify-center mx-auto">Close</button>
                        </>
                        : null}
                                            
                    </div>  
                    )
                })
                : console.log("loading")
                }
            </div>
            <Modal open={open} data={modalData} /> // Suppose this one is your popup. You will consume the item data inside the popup as data. Now use it as you want.
        </div>);
```

Comment: Hi @jifakir I added more context to my original question as well as a codesandbox link, I tried your answer but it seems to be giving me the same results

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the array if you don't want to display all the array

Object(responseData).filter((item)=> item.id = "0")